# Would such a function be of any importance (primality test)?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

While experimenting with some Maths, I came up with a really cool function.

Let's call this function  $\space \beta \space$. Which is a function of a real variable $\space r \space $.

Here is the function:

$$\beta (r) = \tan \Bigg({\pi \over 2 } - {{4 \pi \Gamma(r)} \over r} \Bigg)$$

Where $\space \Gamma(r) \space $ is the *Gamma Function*.

Here is why this function is cool.

Let's take $\space \beta (z) \space$ where $\space z \space$ is a positive integer.

Well, $\space \beta (z) \space$ is only well defined IF AND ONLY IF $\space z \space$ is a prime GREATER than $\space 2$ (I have a proof for this, I didn't just assume it).

So when $\space z \space$ is not prime, $\space \beta (z) \space$ is undefined.

Would this serve ANY importance at all? Is it worth mentioning?

Either way, I found it pretty cool and I hope you do too :).

Comment: Gamma is the gamma function (interpolation of factorials)?

Comment: @William - Yes, sorry I didn't mention that... I'll edit that in.

Comment: @William The idea is that $\frac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is an integer unless $n$ is a prime.

Comment: @almagest - Yes, exactly this... I just used Gamma to extend the domain to non-integers.

Comment: @YuriyS - I mean it's undefined when $z$ is not a prime GREATER than 2 (just added that in, forgot to add it).

Comment: @MaxEchendu, I see. I think this is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: Are you considering r to be an integer?

Comment: @Davey - r is a Real number.

Comment: I suggest you change the title (to something containing 'primality test')

Comment: @YuriyS - What is a primarity test?

Comment: @MaxEchendu, I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: @YuriyS - Ahh I see... I'll edit the title :)

Comment: It’s nice that you were able to think up this. However I don’t think this can be used as an effective prime test. Take for example the $10000$th prime $r=104729$. We have $\frac{2\Gamma(r)}{r} \simeq 3.4\cdot 10^{480256}$ so unless one could think of a smart way of computing it we would need to represent much more than $480000$ digits of this number to be able to show that the argument of the $\tan$-function is not $\pi/2 + n\pi$ making it undefined. It gets exponentially worse for higher primes.

Comment: @Kibble - Ah I understand, though from this I was able to come up with more crazy cool Maths if you're interested. :)

Comment: @Kibble, nice argument, too bad I didn't see it before posting my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is about the usefulness of this function as a primality test (as I assumed in the comments and the OP appeared to agree with me), then it's probably even less useful than the Wilson's theorem on its own.

The primality tests are only needed for really big numbers. First, this one involves computing the factorial of large numbers. And second, for large numbers the function becomes larger (in absolute value), which makes it harder to distinguish the finite case from the infinite one.

It's more convenient to use the reciprocal function:

$$\frac{1}{\beta(r)}=\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4\pi \Gamma(r)}{r} \right)=\tan \left(\frac{4\pi \Gamma(r)}{r} \right)$$

Then it will be zero for every integer $r$ unless $r$ is prime.

But! Its absolute value will steadily decrease with increasing $r$, thus making it harder and harder to determine if a particular large number is prime. See the list plot up to $r=100$:

[image]

Comment: does it have any other zeros tan at the non-primes integers :-) ? (of course I mean the function of the  complex variable $r$)

Comment: @user1952009, can't say, didn't look into this. That's not really related to the question

Comment: Oohh I like this.

Comment: of course it is related to the question : is that function useful ?

Comment: @user1952009, this question is pretty broad. Every function has the potential to be useful. If you have something constructive to say, just post your own answer or comment on the OP

Comment: I think one can safely say that it's definately less useful than Wilson's theorem. Once we have computed $\frac{\Gamma(r)}{r}$ we just $\mod r$ and we'll know if $r$ is prime or not so we can stop.

Comment: @Kibble, to be fair, checking divisibility also requires time. But essentially, yes, I completely agree with your comment